# Events on Power button using Hybrid App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is it possible to fire an event when the device power button is clicked in a hybrid (Ionic) application. I have a requirement where if a user clicks the power button twice an SMS will be sent to other users. Please suggest.